# UtcNow Returns Defective Timestamp

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wrote this system several years ago and don't write any C# now, so this is sort of rusty for me.  I use the code shown below to write out a new record.  For some reason, @TStamp is sometimes not written out correctly (SQL Server 12):

[image]

As can be seen, I'm getting zeroes for the time portion on occasion.  Often, there will be a group of records originating from the same web user but sometimes it is just an isolated incident.  The problem is definitely intermittent and infrequent.

My question is: Is there anything that would cause utcNow to return a timestamp that looks like this (i.e., correct date, zero time)?

```
        protected void MessageDataSrc_Inserting(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Command.Parameters["@CoID"].Value = clsCompany.GetCompanyNumber();
            e.Command.Parameters["@TStamp"].Value = DateTime.UtcNow;
            e.Command.Parameters["@Sender"].Value = clsUser.LoggedInUserName();
            e.Command.Parameters["@Message"].Value = MessageMemoBox.Value;
            e.Command.Parameters["@Memo"].Value = "";
            e.Command.Parameters["@Receiver"].Value = ReceiverComboBox.Value;
            e.Command.Parameters["@NoteCode"].Value = Int32.Parse(noteRadioButtons.SelectedValue);
            e.Command.Parameters["@Urgent"].Value = cboxUrgent.Checked;
            e.Command.Parameters["@Status"].Value = 1;          // new message status
            . . . //unimportant stuff cut out

            c = null;
        }
```

## Edit

The only time this field is updated in the system is if the user edits the item.  The following code pertains to these updates:

```
SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"                
SelectCommand="usp_eSwitchBoard_SelectNewMsgs"
DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Message] WHERE [CoID] = @CoID AND [ID] = @ID" 
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Message] SET [TStamp] = @TStamp, [Sender] = @Sender, (...) WHERE [CoID] = @CoID AND [ID] = @ID"
onselecting="MessageDataSrc_Selecting" onupdating="MessageDataSrc_Updating">
<DeleteParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="CoID" Type="Int32" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int64" />
</DeleteParameters>
<InsertParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="CoID" Type="Int32" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="TStamp" Type="DateTime" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Sender" Type="String" />
```

. . .

## EDIT #2

Stored Px for selecting.  This stored procedure was not used for selecting the sample output above, however, it is used to provide the user with a choice of records available for edit.  The problem field is referenced in the order by, but that's it.

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT M.*, U."NAME" AS "SenderName" FROM "Message" M, "User" U
      WHERE M."CoID" = @COID AND "Receiver" = @RECEIVER AND
            M."Status" = 1 AND
            M."CoID" = U."CoID" AND M."Sender" = U."ID"
              ORDER BY "TStamp" DESC
END
```

## EDIT #3

Source for MessageDataSrc_Updating

```
    protected void MessageDataSrc_Updating(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Command.Parameters["@CoID"].Value = clsCompany.GetCompanyNumber();
        e.Command.Parameters["@Sender"].Value = clsUser.LoggedInUserName();
    }
```

Comment: I don't see why it would return that. I'd be curious what the field type is for TStamp in the database. Also do you have a sample of the SQL insert being sent to the server. I'm wondering if there is a problem with writing or storage.

Comment: It seems like those inserted values are using `DateTime.UtcNow.Date`

Comment: Field type in database is datetime.  Also, I use the following insert parameter definition: <asp:Parameter Name="TStamp" Type="DateTime" />

Comment: I can't seen any reason the value of `DateTime.UtcNow` would result in the equivalent of `DateTime.UtcNow.Date` .Is this the only code that can insert? Is there another process that might be doing erroneous updates?

Comment: Either that or inserts are being done with a stored procedure that is doing incorrect time/date conversions.

Comment: Edited question above to show code for updates.  I did check and we don't have any stored procedures updating this table.

Comment: There is a stored procedure for selecting. I am curious is that used to output the table you diagrammed in your question (showing the entries with zero time) or was that output generated by a simple query?

Comment: @Michael, have edited the Q. again to show that stored Px.  I really appreciate your taking the time to come back to this question.  I am sure it is something simple but I am just not seeing it.  The stored px does provide the value for [TStamp] which is updated on edit.  Unfortunately, I'm not sure whether the affected records have been edited by the user or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60724/discussion-between-michael-petch-and-regularexpression).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Could you please show the code for the `MessageDataSrc_Updating` method?

Comment: Also, are you passing anything for the `<UpdateParameters>` section?  You cut your code short in Edit #1.   (See also the very last example [in these docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/xt50s8kz.aspx))

Answer (score 1):

In the method for MessageDataSrc_Updating, I don't see the inclusion of the @TStamp parameter used in

```
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Message] SET [TStamp] = @TStamp, [Sender] = @Sender, (...) WHERE [CoID] = @CoID AND [ID] = @ID"
```

Shouldn't you include this parameter in the method as follows??

```
protected void MessageDataSrc_Updating(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{
    e.Command.Parameters["@CoID"].Value = clsCompany.GetCompanyNumber();
    e.Command.Parameters["@Sender"].Value = clsUser.LoggedInUserName();

    e.Command.Parameters["@TStamp"].Value = DateTime.UtcNow; // Appears to be missing
}
```

Is it possible that these are just updated entries with the timestamp set at the current date at midnight (equivalent of DateTime.UtcNow.Date) due to a default value set somewhere.

Comment: This issue has now been resolved.  We found a devexpress grid that was doing an update to the record in another location we had forgotten about.  It was set, as was suggested by Zer0 and Michael above, to update using "Date" only.  Thanks to everyone who replied on this problem.